# Give the path for compile_commands.json file to coc-clangd

Tags: yocto, neovim, coc.nvim

so I'm a developer working mostly with c using yocto/openembedded for developing our products. I'm trying to set up my nvim with coc-cland as an IDE, but having some problems.

So what I want is to give languageserver the `compile_commands.json` file. I have the setup working when the `compile_commands.json` is in the "root of the src dir" but the `compile_commands.json` is normally not generated in the source folder instead it is generated to *<root of src dir>/oe-workdir/<project name>/compile_commands.json*. How do I tell coc to use that file if it exists? Finding the file is easy using shell script, but what variable shall I set and where?

My `:CocConfig` looks like:

```
{ 
  "languageserver": {
    "coc-clangd": {
      "command": "clangd",
      "rootPatterns": [ ".git/", "compile_flags.txt", "compile_commands.json"],
      "filetypes": ["c", "cc", "cpp", "c++", "objc", "objcpp"]
    }                                     
  }                                       
}
```

I have found some relevant git for coc-clangd (https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd) where it states that I can set the clangd.arguments but I need to do it dynamically as the <project name> folder changes name from project to project, can I do it in the `:CocConfig` or can I do it in my vimrc/init.vim?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd/issues/182 if work for you

Comment: Based upon clang's [documentation](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html#project-setup), if your compile_commands.json is not within `$SRC` or `$SRC/build`, then you should symlink a copy of it to your `$SRC` dir. In other words, redirecting coc-clangd probably isn't something you should be asking it to do for you.